# Command line to Silently remove Google Chrome APPs (PWA)

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, uninstall, command-line-arguments, silent-install

I need to remove all Google Chrome APPs (PWA) using the least effort possible.
Once I'm managing almost 12.000 workstations, I need to do it centrally, by using a CMD/PS1 to accomplish it.

I've been searching and I've found this

`"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory=Default --uninstall-app-id=plchpjihggghlhalnelyyylijhbmcxxx`

This would be awesome if I can avoid the confirmation pop-up that it shows (view next image).

Confirmation Pop-Up:
[image]

I've also tried to use WMIC but had no luck with it because WMIC is not able to find and list it, so I have no way to invocate the appropriate APP name.

Has anyone already found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Any luck figuring that out? Google Chrome recently released update that installs default google wpa apps automatically.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).